# xmlhttprequest(xhr) object difference between xhr.onerror and xhr.upload.onerror

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, xmlhttprequest

This might be a very obvious question but please explain what is the difference between `xhr` and `xhr.upload`?

My use case is that I am uploading a file to a server but suppose the server goes down. In this case should I handle `xhr.onerror` or `xhr.upload.onerror`

Basically, as mentioned in the question, when to use xhr and when to use `xhr.upload` where `xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();`

Another newbie question on the same, is it related to how GET vs POST/PUT are handled?

Answer (score 5):

`xhr.onerror` fires when there is a failure on the network level. If the error only exists on the application level, e.g., an HTTP error code is sent, then onload still fires. 
You need to test the returned status code explicitly in your onreadystatuschange handler.

where as `xhr.upload.onerror` fires something happend when you are trying to upload, this is basically application level function just like `xhr.upload.Onprogress`.

This upload always depends upon the ajax post method.

Comment: Thanks, this clarifies a lot. However, I still can't understand the difference between xhr and xhr.upload i.e. xhr.addEventListener("error", errorhandler) and xhr.upload.addEventListener("error", errorhandler) {same for progress event}. Can you provide an example when xhr.onerror will fire and when xhr.upload.onerror will fire (for example, if server replies with 500/Internal Error). If I can use .onreadystatechange event, then whats the use of xhr.upload ?